# Trouble using Vlookup in a SUMIFS function statement

Tags: excel

I have an accounting spreadsheet where I am trying to create an analysis area which populates from the 12 month Actuals data so that when I enter a month, the function (in this case a SUMIF) will update the formula based on the specific column which contains the monthly data.

For example:

Cell O2 = the user input Month, for example:  APR

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Product     Department      ACTUALS-APR ACTUALS-MAY ACTUALS-JUN …..
```

I have a Lookup table called: “MonthActuals” which looks as follows:

```
Month       Column
JAN     F
FEB     G   
MAR     H
APR     I
Etc…..
```

I have hard coded the other criteria to look up the actual amount, which are the Product and Department.   So, the SUMIFS looks at the hard-coded Product and Department, but needs to look up the column for the month that the user wants the figures.

Here is my formula that works correctly WITHOUT using a VLOOKUP ( I hard-coded the month):

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$F$8:$F$328,Sheet2!$B$8:$B$328," Total Glass Purchases ",Sheet2!$C$8:$C$328,"Scrap")
```

Here is my VLOOKUP which works correctly:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,MonthActuals,2,FALSE)
```

HOWEVER, when I replace the “F” column reference in the formula with a VLOOKUP formula, I get a #value error message.

Here is the formula I used when I tried to combine the VLOOKUP with the SUMIFS.

```
'SUMIFS(VLOOKUP(O1,MONTHACTUALS,2,FALSE)&”8:”&VLOOKUP(O1,MONTHACTUALS,2,FALSE)&“328”,Sheet2!$B$8:$B$328,"Total Glass Purchases",Sheet2!$C$8:$C$328,"Scrap")
```

I don't want to use any VBA, but only use functions to do these calculations.

Answer (score 2):

First be careful of `”` they are not recognized by Excel, make sure they are all `"`

Next you will need to use INDIRECT()

```
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Sheet2!" & VLOOKUP(O1,MONTHACTUALS,2,FALSE) & "8:" & VLOOKUP(O1,MONTHACTUALS,2,FALSE) & "328"),Sheet2!$B$8:$B$328,"Total Glass Purchases",Sheet2!$C$8:$C$328,"Scrap")
```

Comment: @Hilly1 if you are trying to mark as correct click the check mark.